# How can I split BigQuery results into batches of a specific size and save them as multiple CSV files?

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, export-to-csv

I have limited experience with BigQuery and recently I have had an issue where I need to provide output in CSV format specifically and I cannot save the results if it is more that 150,000 rows or so as a local csv files.
I have read about a few solutions using Google Storage but I was wondering if I could write a SQL code in BQ to split my output into batches of no more than 150,000.
I have used something very simple that works fine for 2-3 batches but is extremely inefficient for larger sizes. Say if I had 1,500,000 and needed 10 batches.

```
SELECT *
FROM output_tbl
LIMIT 150,000

save the results in a BQ table, temp_tbl1

SELECT *
FROM output_tbl
WHERE key_column NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT key_column FROM temp_tbl1)
LIMIT 150,000

save the results in another BQ table, temp_tbl2

SELECT *
FROM output_tbl
WHERE key_column NOT IN 
                     (SELECT DISTINCT key_column FROM temp_tbl1
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT DISTINCT key_column FROM temp_tbl2)
LIMIT 150,000
```

And continue the process... This is very manual and inefficient. Is there a way to generate all batches at once?

Comment: Hi n_user184, Could you clarify your requirement? Do you want to save the outputs in multiple csv files or in a single csv file? Why do you want to do it in batches as BigQuery supports exporting data with millions of rows in csv format using [export data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#exporting_data_to_csv_format)?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery can do pretty much what you're after out of the box.

Except the 150k rows (it will roughly size the files between 150-200MB), it's just too easy:

```
EXPORT DATA
OPTIONS (
   uri = 'gs://bucket/folder/*.csv',
   format = 'CSV',
   overwrite = true,
   header = true,
   field_delimiter = ',')
AS (SELECT field1, field2
    FROM mydataset.table1
    ORDER BY field1
);
```

Check the docs for more details: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#sql